# Covert Form Recognizer logic app results to CSV in a logic app

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-form-recognizer

I've started to experiment a little with the Form Recognizer in azure but am stuck on how to easily convert the recognized table into a usable data structure such as CSV. When using the https://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net/ tool I am able to download the table to CSV so am now looking to replicate this in a logic app. I have managed to get the data into the below format which is columnindex, rowindex and text but now need to somehow pivot this into csv.

```
"0,0,Weight",
"0,0,----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Weight",
"0,0,----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Weight",
"0,0,Weight",
"1,0,Qty",
"0,0,----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Weight",
"0,0,Weight",
"0,0,Weight",
"1,0,Qty",
"1,0,Qty",
"1,0,Qty",
```

Not sure if I'm going down the right route here and can not seem to find anything helpful online so I'm hoping that there is a simple way to do this which I have not found?

Answer (score 0):

Logic app has a Form Recognizer connector which you can easily use to extract all the information - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/formrecognizer/
If you are using the JSON than tables have row index, column index and span index, header indication etc. that can be used to convert to csv for example -

```
        "tables": [
                {
                    "rows": 5,
                    "columns": 3,
                    "cells": [
                        {
                            "rowIndex": 0,
                            "columnIndex": 0,
                            "text": "Title of each class",
                            "boundingBox": [
                                0.5662,
                                4.8913,
                                3.8367,
                                4.8975,
                                3.8367,
                                5.1231,
                                0.5662,
                                5.1231
                            ],
                            "elements": [
                                "#/readResults/0/lines/24/words/0",
                                "#/readResults/0/lines/24/words/1",
                                "#/readResults/0/lines/24/words/2",
                                "#/readResults/0/lines/24/words/3"
                            ],
                            "isHeader": true
                        },
```

Comment: Thanks Neta, this is exactly my question, I know it is in JSON and should be fairly easy to convert but my question is how? I have tried lots of different things but cannot seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/python/FormRecognizer/rest/python-invoices.md#sample-python-script-to-extract-invoice-or-a-batch-of-invoices-into-a-csv-file) code on converting the invoice output into csv file.